# Design Bug: Horizontal Lines between comments too bold

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It strikes me that 90% of complaints about design seem to be "Make this minor element stand out more on the page."

So, it is nice to make an opposite request:

The horizontal lines between comments standard out too much. (Hat Tip: [@Alex](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/new-skeptics-design-has-launched#comment3877_1547))

They make the comments seem more disjointed and unrelated than they need to.

Suggestion from a design ignoramus: Give them wider margins, so they don't extend past the margins of the comments and/or make them a lighter grey.

Comment: I'd make some (if not all) horizontal lines grey instead of black.

Comment: @Fabian: Yes, that's one of the options I suggested. For the record, there are already two grades of horizontal line: 1 and 2 pixel.

Comment: if the contrast is really bothering we can adjust the color in css. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been changed to be a nice mellow light grey. thank you