# Design: orange vs yellow?

Tags: feature-request, design

In addition to my [previous suggestions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1534/5832), I also want to suggest orange color over yellow:

[image: caption]

> **NOTE:** changes are to the main site (not meta)

**Changes made:**

- Logo colors (white text, orange brackets)
- Tags (new design)
- 'Ask Question' button (lower-cased text, orange background, black text)
- Tabs (grey background)
- Some links (orange text)
- Featured Badge (orange background)
- <sub>(and other minor things)</sub>

---

What do you think?

Comment: anyone know how to make my image full-sizable on click?

Comment: I like it.  I would also lighten up the dark gray on the outside.  I think the meta color would be great.  Could go dark in the meta.  I would make the links that color as well.  They are really important here.

Comment: @ajax333221 You can't

Comment: @ajax333221 try `[![caption][1]](http://imgur.com/gallery/J4qLn)`, and at the bottom, `[1]: http://i.imgur.com/J4qLn.jpg`

Comment: @Sklivvz better: `[![caption][1]][1]` or else you are just being redundant :-P

Comment: @neal, links are different, but interesting! I didn't know you could repeat the same "pointer". Good to know.

Comment: @Sklivvz you can use a link reference as many times as you want in a post ^_^

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, please change the yellow currently in use. I find it far too 'bright' to be comfortable to look at. Gold badges, tag counts and tag highlights in particular. Where this shade is used on a black background it's ok, but on a white background it's far to bright to be nice to look at.

Since this is sceptics, I used a [colour contrast checker](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html), and the yellow on white does not even pass WCAG 2 AA Compliant, the lowest metric on that site. It's a very long way off passing any of the metrics. I'd recommend a more orangey hue, particularly for badges.

Comment: neither the green `#83CF20` against white when a browsing questions that are answered (but not accepted)